# $\int \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}\frac 1{x^2} dx$

Tags: integration

> How can we integrate
>   $$
> \int \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}\frac 1{x^2} \,  dx
> $$

I thought about substituting $u=\frac 1x$ to transform the integral into a slightly-simpler looking one:
$$
-\int \sqrt{\frac{1-u}{1+u}} \,  du
$$
Am I on the right track?

Following @Shobhit's comment, I let $u=\cos (2w)=\cos^2 w - \sin^2 w$, so that $du=-2 \sin(2w) \,  dw = -4 \sin w \cos w \,  dw$ and so
\begin{align}
\int \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}\frac 1{x^2} dx &= -\int \sqrt{\frac{1-u}{1+u}} \,  du \\ 
&= 4 \int |\tan w| \sin w \cos w \,  dw \\ 
&= 4 \int \sin^2 w \, dw
\end{align}
If this is correct, then I can finish the rest of this integral on my own.

Comment: Yes. Now let u=cos2x

Comment: @Shobhit Should I let $u=cos 2w$ or some variable other than $x$? Because I already have $x$ to begin with in the problem.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. As u see fit.

Comment: $$\cos2w=1-2\sin^2w$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The faster way to integrate such a function is to let 
$$
u=\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}
$$
so that
$$
x= \frac{u^2+1}{1-u^2} \implies dx=\frac{4 u}{\left(u^2-1\right)^2}du
$$
the integral thus becomes
$$
\int \sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}\frac 1{x^2} dx=\int u \frac{(1-u^2)^2}{(1+u^2)^2} \frac{4 u}{\left(u^2-1\right)^2}du=\int \frac{4u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}du
$$
and now you can use Partial Fraction Decomposition, which goes off easy, you must obtain:
$$
\int \frac{4u^2}{(1+u^2)^2}du=2 \arctan(u)-\frac{2 u}{u^2+1}+c=2 \arctan \left(\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x+1}}\right)-\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}+c
$$

Answer (score 2):

After your substitution from $\displaystyle x= \frac{1}{u}$ $$I = -\int\sqrt{\frac{1-u}{1+u}}du = \int\frac{u-1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du = \int\frac{u}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du-\int\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-u^2}}du$$

$$I = -\sqrt{1-u^2}-\arcsin(u)+\mathcal{C} = -\frac{\sqrt{x^2-1}}{x}-\arcsin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)+\mathcal{C}$$